# mapMaybe for keys in Data.Map

Tags: haskell

I want to map the following function over the keys of a `Map`

```
f :: a -> Maybe b
```

and discard the `Nothing` keys and keep the `Just` keys, but extracted from the `Just`. Just like `Map.mapMaybe`, but for keys

```
mapMaybeKeys :: (a -> Maybe b) -> Map a c -> Map b c
```

I searched Hoogle for this type signature but didn't find anything.

I could do this:

```
mapMaybeKeys f
    = Map.toList
    . catMaybes
    . fmap (fmap swap . traverse f . swap)
    . Map.toList
```

or:

```
mapMaybeKeys f
   = Map.mapKeys fromJust
   . Map.delete Nothing
   . Map.mapKeys f
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: `mapKeys` is implemented in terms of `fromList` and `foldrWithKey`, it is easy to modify that code to remove `Nothing`s. Not sure it will be more elegant though.

Comment: your first version is very clever and nice. you of course meant `swap`, not `flip` (both of them). also needs to be tweaked as  `catMaybes . map (fmap swap . sequenceA . swap . first f) . M.toList` or something.

Comment: actually, what about the possibility of `f` introducing duplicate keys where there were none? so it mustn't be simple `fromList` for the final processing step, but a more complicated call, like `fromListWith (++) . map (second pure)` or something, but it necessarily changes the type. or maybe you're fine with getting just the last of the duplicates in the final Map.

Comment: @WillNess Oops...yes I meant swap!

Comment: @WillNess Right now, I'm not concerned with duplicates

Answer (score 4):

With list comprehensions,

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Control.Arrow (first)

mapMaybeKeys :: Ord b => (a -> Maybe b) -> Map a c -> Map b c
mapMaybeKeys f m = 
   M.fromList [ (b,a) | (Just b, a) <- map (first f) . M.toList $ m ]
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s not bad with `foldMapWithKey` (or `foldrWithKey`), without going through an intermediate list.

```
mapMaybeKeys :: (Ord b) => (a -> Maybe b) -> Map a c -> Map b c

mapMaybeKeys f = Map.foldMapWithKey
  (\ k a -> foldMap (\ k' -> M.singleton k' a) (f k))

-- or:
mapMaybeKeys f = Map.foldMapWithKey (flip (foldMap . flip M.singleton) . f)

-- or:
mapMaybeKeys = M.foldMapWithKey . fmap (flip (foldMap . flip M.singleton))
```

The inner `foldMap` produces an empty map if the key function returns `Nothing`. You could add some helper definitions to make this a simpler-looking pipeline of compositions by avoiding the `flip`s. Note that you need the `Ord` constraint to use `b` as the keys of the resulting map.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Will Ness and @Jon Purdy, I like your solutions, but with some adjustments, I think I like my original solution best:

```
import Data.Bitraversable (bitraverse)
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

mapMaybeKeys :: (Ord b) => (a -> Maybe b) -> Map a c -> Map b c
mapMaybeKeys f
  = Map.fromList
  . catMaybes
  . fmap (bitraverse f Just)
  . Map.toList
```

Comment: side note, here `bitraverse f Just = uncurry (liftA2 (,)) . (f *** Just)`.